# NodeJs express send json data to backbone

Tags: json, node.js, backbone.js, express

Hi I'm not getting the reason why this is not working.
I'm trying to send a simple json object to my client, which is receiving the data by backbone fetch.
It works just fine with the json test link, but somehow not with the local nodeJs server

Server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('/js', express.static(__dirname + "/js"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var obj = { "foo" : "bar" };
    res.json(obj)
});

app.listen(8888);
```

client:

```
define('APP',
    ["jquery", 
    "underscore", 
    "backbone"], 

    function() {
    var APP = {
        init: function(){
            getModel();
        }
    }

    function getModel(){

        var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            // http://localhost:8888
            //http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two <-- works
            url: 'http://localhost:8888',
        });

        myCollection = new Collection();
        myCollection.fetch({
                error: function (collection, response) {
                    console.log('error', response);
                },
                success: function (collection, response) {
                    console.log('success', response);
                }
            });

    }

    APP.init();
    return APP;

});
```

I'm not getting a response on client side.

Thank you for helping me out

**edit: I browsed for similar questions, but none worked somehow **

Comment: Can you see the json response if you take http://localhost:8888 in your browser?

Comment: yep I see it in my network -> json tab, but also receiving a 304 - not modified status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what is the issue in this case and I will answer my own question, due to the fact that some other people might face the same problem.

The issue is, that the header was not set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Since I only use firefox I did not see this error, but chrome showed me.

Here is the working code for server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('/js', express.static(__dirname + "/js"));

var obj = { "foo" : "bar" };
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.json(obj)
}); 

app.listen(8888);
```